# Rails forms - 'Other' option with checkboxes / radio buttons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to have in a form within Rails - an "Other" option in a form where the user can input their own text. Any help / ideas would be very helpful.

```
 <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:    
 registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>


<%= f.input :apples, 
                label: "How many apples?", 
                required: true, 
                as: :radio_buttons, 
                collection: [['0','0'], ['1', '1'], ['Other' , '**user input**']],
                input_html: {class: "form-basic" } ,
                item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to make a separate field called something like "other_option" and create a number field input in the form. In your radio buttons input, give the option 'Other' a value like '-1'. Then in your controller action, check the value of this radio buttons input. If it is '-1', then overwrite the value with user's input in "other_option" field. You might need to add some js validation and css to make it looks better.